# Draw grid on transparent Mat

Tags: java, opencv, mat

I would like to create a Mat with a grid on a transparent background that I can lay on top of other Mats. I struggle with the transparent part and to laying on top

```
Mat image = imread("pic.jpg");
Mat grid = new Mat(image.size(), CV_8UC4, new Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0);

for (//times)
    // draw grid with: line(grid, ... )     

grid.copyTo(image);
```

First of all the grid Mat is not transparent at all it is black. Isn't scalar constructed like this?

```
new Scalar(Blue, Green, Red, Alpha)
```

Also how do I overlay an image with another one? This is just overwriting.

Comment: please understand, that opencv, being mainly a computer-vision api, not a desktop-publishing one, won't honor alpha channels *at all* with built-in operations. you'd have to mainly roll your own, and again the java api, not known to to be especially pixel-friendly, might be the wrong way approaching this.

Comment: create a second mat: `Mat gridMask = new Mat(image.size(), CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0);` then when you draw the grid, draw the same pixels on the `gridMask` (in white, or anything != 0) and change to `grid.copyTo(image,mask);`

Comment: In your case to overlay two Mats you can just multiply one by another (pixel by pixel not matrix multiplication of course :) )

Comment: @Micka yeah i have found `add()`. Yours seems to be shorter though. Thanks!

Comment: @TomTom depends on what you want to do. If you want to merge/blend the grid image and the original image, you need some weighted sum or sth. If you want to replace, you need copy

Comment: @Micka You are right. Do you mind writing an answer with `copyTo()` and `addWeighted()`

Comment: if you may choose, do you want BGR oder BGRA results?

Comment: BGRA. I don't quite understand the Alpha value of BGRA.

Comment: you cant display alpha values in openCV (e.g. imshow) correctly, but writing as a png should work. I'll write a C++ answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68402/discussion-between-tomtom-and-micka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample program written in C++ but it should be very analogue in java:

```
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna.png");

    cv::Mat inputBGRA;
    cv::cvtColor(input, inputBGRA, CV_BGR2BGRA);

    cv::Mat gridSolid = cv::Mat(input.size(), inputBGRA.type(), cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));
    cv::Mat gridMask = cv::Mat(input.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

    cv::Mat gridAlpha = cv::Mat(input.size(), inputBGRA.type(), cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));


    cv::line(gridSolid, cv::Point(0,0), cv::Point(512,512), cv::Scalar(0,255,0,255), 10);
    cv::line(gridSolid, cv::Point(0,512), cv::Point(512,0), cv::Scalar(0,255,0,255), 10);
    cv::line(gridMask, cv::Point(0,0), cv::Point(512,512), cv::Scalar(255), 10);    // single channel
    cv::line(gridMask, cv::Point(0,512), cv::Point(512,0), cv::Scalar(255), 10);    // single channel

    // copy and use the mask. copying eliminates the original values where the mask is set
    cv::Mat outputCopy = inputBGRA.clone();
    gridSolid.copyTo(outputCopy,gridMask);



    // here set the scalar alpha value to less than 255
    // both lines use different alpha values
    cv::line(gridAlpha, cv::Point(0,0), cv::Point(512,512), cv::Scalar(0,255,0,120), 10);
    cv::line(gridAlpha, cv::Point(0,512), cv::Point(512,0), cv::Scalar(0,255,0,180), 10);

    cv::Mat outputWeightSum = inputBGRA.clone();
    //cv::addWeighted(inputBGRA, 0.5, gridAlpha, 0.5, 0, outputWeightSum);

    // manually add weighted sum PER ALPHA VALUE:
    for(int y=0; y<outputWeightSum.rows; ++y)
        for(int x=0; x<outputWeightSum.cols; ++x)
        {
            // the bigger the alpha value, the less of the original image is kept at that pixel
            cv::Vec4b imgPix = outputWeightSum.at<cv::Vec4b>(y,x);
            cv::Vec4b gridPix = gridAlpha.at<cv::Vec4b>(y,x);

            // use alpha channel vor blending
            float blendpart = (float)gridPix[3]/(float)255;

            // set pixel value to blended value
            outputWeightSum.at<cv::Vec4b>(y,x) = blendpart * gridPix + (1.0f-blendpart) * imgPix;
        }
```

in fact you dont need the alpha channel in this example but if you have more complex "grids" with differing alpha values, it might be nice.

I get these results:

1. method: copy:

[image]

2. method: blend with alpha channel:

[image]

Comment: there is little bug in the code: the alpha channel of the result image should not be a blending of both inputs, but the maximum of their alpha values I guess... otherwise the whole pixel will be part transparent in the end (e.g. if saved as a png).